# Selenium inconsistent in finding element with text edited by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium

I am having trouble verifying the presence of a WebElement. Below is the HTML code for the HTML element.

`<div class="notifications top-right" style="right: 310px;"></div>`

It is a div element that is affected by a `<script>` element later once a form has been submitted. The `<div>` element will popup in the top right corner of the webpage, display a message, and then disappear. Below is the javascript that accomplishes this.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var message = 'Sample text sample text sample text';
        $('.notifications.top-right').css('right', $(window).width() - $("#content").width() + 200 + 'px');
        $('.notifications.top-right').notify({
            message: { text: message },
            closeable: false
        }).show();
    });
</script>
```

In the java code, I click on a button, which submits a form, and then I am taken to a new page, where I wait for the popup to appear to verify its presence, and then I move on with the test. However, searching for the popup is inconsistent and only succeeds some of the time. If anyone has any ideas on solutions, I would appreciate it. Below is the selenium code.

```
public void Approve() {
    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", Link_Approve());
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), ' sample text')]"))));
}
```

Comment: is popup comes and disappear or stays like that until another actions means close like that?

Comment: It appears and then disappears by itself with no clicks @muraliselenium

Comment: What happens when it doesn't succeed? Is there an error message or ? Have you tried searching for the popup (without specifying contained text) and then pulling the text from it?